# PowerShell in conEmu has different PATH from cmd

Tags: command-line, powershell, path, openssl, conemu

Why does PowerShell on conEmu have a different PATH from cmd?

I see this when I do `openssl version` in PowerShell I see that 2007 version and in cmd I see the 2013 version....

This is my startup commandline in conemu

```
powershell -cur_console:d:h:
```

How do I make it so powershell on conemu will have the same path as cmd?

Comment: Again. What is the difference in your PATH variables in ConEmu box and standard windows box? What prints `$env:PATH` in both terminals?

Comment: BTW, "-cur_console:d:h:" is not fully correct. "h:" means change drive, not path... May be not determined in some cases... Use "-cur_console:d:h:\" to guaranteed change working path to "h:\".

Answer (score 1):

@Maximus, thanks for the help. Seems that a restart makes `powershell` grab the path or something.

Now its all sorted :)

Comment: This should be a comment in response to Maximus and not an answer, Maximus should have posted his comment as an answer. Someone else easily can to gain points, including you - include it in your answer above and accept it!